# JQuery code not working in IE 8

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms

This code is working in firefox but on IE 8 it returns nothing

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("~/test/test.aspx")%>';

   // Test
        $('#<%=ddlTest.ClientID%>').change(function(){
            var trgId = $(this+'input:checked').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url : pageUrl+ '/getRecs',
                data : '{categ: "' +trgId + '"}',
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType:"json",
                success:function(msg)
                    { 
                        bindCategories(msg)
                    }
                });
        });
});

$('#divLoad').ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).show();
});

$('#divLoad').ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).hide();
});

function bindCategories(msg)
        {
             if(msg.hasOwnProperty("d"))
                alert(msg.d);
             else
             {
                 $('select[id$=<%=ddlTrg.ClientID %>] > option').remove();

                 $.each(msg, function() {
                    $('#<%=ddlTrg.ClientID %>').append($('<option></option>').val(this['Id']).html(this['Name']));
                 });
             }
        }

</script>`
```

Comment: Is $(this+'input:checked') the way you select an option inside a <select> ?  I was just wondering what "this" was in the changed event handler.. Do you think it's the ajax call that's erroring?  Have you tried the debugger using F12?

Comment: I'm sorry. I am just a starter with JQuery, I thought the id for the control was found with the previous  $('#<%=ddlTest.ClientID%>').change(function() so I might be able to fetch it again by using 'this'. I corrected it now but still it won't work in IE, all works good in FF. Damien

Comment: I think there is some trouble with the (msg) response. Whenever I try to use like alert(msg); It shows me the objects in firefox but on IE it says 'undefined'. Can't figure it out yet.

Comment: I am using asp.net 2.0 webforms with JQ 1.4.2.

Comment: @Damien - I think this is the problem, `data : '{categ: "' +trgId + '"}',`. How about this, `data : { 'categ': trgId },`

Comment: Thanks Reigel, you were absolutely right ! It's working great now. It was just that the webmethod took an input parameter as string which I quoted with "trgId", I did not knew the parameter name also needs to be quoted with "". Do you have any link about these basics ? Also the prev code worked in firefox but failed in IE (that was which made me think the code was correct) . If you would post your answer as separate reply I will mark it as answer. =) Damein.

Comment: Also, this single quote and double quote confuses me. Do we enclose string parameters in double quotes & selectors in single quotes ? I have seen people use selectors with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line doesn't look right?

```
var trgId = $(this+'input:checked').val();
```

`this` is an html element so you can't just use it like you are.

Do you mean something like:

```
var trgId = $('#' + this.id).val();
```

or

```
var trgId = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
```

Comment: Thanks I corrected that. It still works in firefox but not in IE. Problem is that function bindCategories() won't fill the drop downlist in IE however it works in FF.

Comment: @Damien - Do you get any javascript errors? Have you used the built in IE tools (F12) or Fiddler to try and see what is going on?

Comment: Geoff, I don't know how to use the IE tools for debugging, might have to read a tutorial on it.

Comment: The selector was somehow working in FF, now its working in IE.